# ValueError: too many values to unpack error

Tags: python

I have this list of lists of pairs of part of speech consist of words and its tags, and I used the following function to iterate over this list and select the pairs that meet if statement but I have an error. This is the list:

```
[[('After', 'IN'), ('generating', 'VBG')],
 [('generating', 'VBG'), ('all', 'DT')],
 [('all', 'DT'), ('feature', 'NN')],
 [('feature', 'NN'), ('spaces', 'NNS')]]
```

This is the function:

```
def select_posesPairs(tweet):
    D=[]
    s = getTokenss(tweet)
    for first,second in s:
        for word,tag in second:
            if tag =='NN':
                D.append(word)

    return D
```

And this is the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: It's a list of lists of pairs and not a list of pairs.

Comment: Looks like a dictionary would be better suited here.

Answer (score 0):

you have a nested list. and the first iteration is on the outter list

you can do

```
for sub_list in s:
    for tuple_data in sub_list:
        if tuple_data[1] == 'NN'
```

result

```
In [3]: s = [[('After', 'IN'), ('generating', 'VBG')],
   ...:  [('generating', 'VBG'), ('all', 'DT')],
   ...:  [('all', 'DT'), ('feature', 'NN')],
   ...:  [('feature', 'NN'), ('spaces', 'NNS')]]

In [4]: for sub_list in s:
   ...:     for tup in sub_list:
   ...:         print(tup[1])
   ...:
IN
VBG
VBG
DT
DT
NN
NN
NNS
```

Comment: The problem is that we have lists of list for example [('After', 'IN'), ('generating', 'VBG')] is one item in s list which is a list itself consist of two items each item is word and its tag and when we use if tup[1] ==NN we need to know which word can be appended

Comment: @IbrahimDangou I don't get what you are saying. If you want the word, just do `tup[0]` ??? tup is a tuple which contains both the word and the tag